# use a decorator for a POST request only in python

Tags: python, django, decorator

I'd like to define a decorator which will apply another_decorator if condition is met,
and which will just simply the function otherwise.

Below doesn't work..

```
def decorator_for_post(view_func):

    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            return another_decorator(view_func) # we apply **another_decorator**
        return view_func  # we just use the view_func

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
class Request:
    def __init__ (self, method):
        self.method = method

def another_decorator (f):
    print ("another")
    return f

def decorator_for_post (f):
    def g (request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            return another_decorator (f) (request, *args, **kwargs)
        return f (request, *args, **kwargs)
    return g

@decorator_for_post
def x (request):
    print ("doing x")

print ("GET")
x (Request ("GET") )
print ("POST")
x (Request ("POST") )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually call the function within your wrapper.

```
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: concise, but took some time to figure out I need another_decorator(view_func)(request, *args, **kwargs) as well :(